Applying convex multiplicative functions to Brocard's Problem
Brocard's problem asks if there are integer solutions to $n! = (x-1)(x+1)$ other than the cases of $n =$ $4$, $5$, $7$. Knowing the only shared divisor of the factors on the right is 2, would it be possible to have some convex multiplicative function $f(n)$ such that
$$f\left(\frac{N!}{2}\right) > f\left(\frac{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n!+1}\right\rfloor-1}{2}\right)f\left(\left\lfloor \sqrt{n!+1}\right\rfloor+1\right)$$
holds for all sufficiently large $N$ with $N \geq n$? (Of course, the division by 2 could be on the other factor, but I don't think it really matters.) If such a function were to exist it effectively solve the problem, and all that one would need to show is that a lower bound of the left side is always higher than an upper bound on the right side, right? For many common arithmetic functions, the statement doesn't hold. It would need to somehow produce big values (assuming not complex) for numbers similar to factorials, showing some sort of "factorialness."

There are no other solutions to Brocard's problem [$n! + 1 = m^2$] besides n = 4,5,7.
The proof of the above has been published in the 'Indian Journal of Advanced Mathematics (IJAM)', Volume-4 Issue-1, April 2024, Page # 25-28. The proof is available online at: https://www.ijam.latticescipub.com/portfolio-item/b117404021024/.
The proof shows that if $(n,m)$ is to be a solution to Brocard's problem, then $n! = 4AB$, where $A$ is even, $B$ is odd, and $|A – B| = 1$.
If $n$ is even ($n = 2x$) and $> 4$, the proof shows that necessarily $$A = (2x)!!/(4y)$$ and $$B = (2x-1)!!(y)$$ for some odd $y > 1$. Next, it shows that $x < 2y$ which leads to an inequality in $x$: $$[(2x-1)!!(x) \pm 1]^2 – 1 – (2x)! < 0,$$ for which there is no solution when $x \geqslant 3$.
If $n$ is odd, there is a similar procedure.

You are directing us to an article. Are you willing to summarize the relevant points here, on this site? You may click "Edit" to improve your answer.

We discourage link-only answers, because we don't want to be just a link farm, and because if the link stops working, this answer becomes useless.  Can you provide a full citation (journal, paper title, author), and summarize the main ideas?
